# Add Two Rows of parsed Data of Xml in java

Tags: java, collections

parsed this xml in java code, but problem is that i want to calculate lost percentage will be calculated by adding the lostperc of both direction(upstream,downstream). Below is the Java Code So far What I have Done.

```
<RR cid="1460458819000" sid="92555" eod="0">
        <RR1 direction="0" statStatus="1792"  lostperc="1" />
        <RR1 direction="1" statStatus="1792" lostperc="1" />
</RR>
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);// here I put above Xml  
 List<AccedianWrapper> accedianWrappers =accedianResponse.getList();
    for (AccedianWrapper accedianWrapper : accedianWrappers) {
       String dir = accedianWrapper.getDirection();
         if (dir.equals("0") || dir.equals("1")) {
           System.out.println("direction " + dir);
             lstPer = Integer.valueOf(accedianWrapper.getLostperc());
               System.out.println(lstPer);
                    }
                    //                  
            lstPer = Integer.valueOf(accedianWrapper.getLostperc());
                    //System.out.println(lstPer);
                 if (lstPer >= 1) {
                  if (!alrtCount.containsKey(lid)) {
                    alrtCount = Collections.singletonMap(lid, count);
                    } else {
              int countn = alrtCount.get(lid);
                alrtCount = Collections.singletonMap(lid, countn + 1);
                    if(countn > 4) {
                    System.out.println("get 5 times consecutive lost percentage");
                    alrtCount = Collections.singletonMap(lid, count);
                 }
                   }
                    System.out.println(alrtCount);
               } else{
                   if (alrtCount.containsKey(lid)) {
                alrtCount = Collections.singletonMap(lid, count);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                    From accedianResponse I get List Of accedianWrapper which Is POjo and Having Element of Xml,By Iterating Over AccedianWrapper i get LostPerc and Direction as well.But My Requirement is to Combine the Direction=0 and Direction=1 and Add the lostperc, currently i a getting Single row one by one in loop getting lostperc.
                I am sorry if i written anything wrong .... please help me out.....
```

Comment: @jordi Castilla hi.. you have solution

Comment: @jordiCastilla If you not understand what i am asking please ask ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JordiCastilla this might be understandable ..... how i group two row data from list.

Comment: this is understandable, but we will need more info: code showing problem you're facing, demo data, current and expected result.